# How to make an iframe secure?

Tags: html, css, security, internet-explorer, iframe

[image: eror]

This error keeps on appearing. How to remove this? My site is an https and the content of the iframe is also coming from an https source, I don't know what seems to be the problem?

// edited:

this is the detailed error that appears. and yes, I am using IE6. 
[image]

Comment: How do you know it's the `<iframe>` causing that warning? Comment it out and see if your page still generates the warning. Also, *what version of IE are you running?* That looks like IE6.

Comment: I am trying to test it on ie6 since some of our clients are running ie6 and this is bothering them.

Comment: See my answer below.  It is very likely that non-secure resources in your page or iFrame are to blame.

Answer (score 1):

There are nonsecure items in either your page or in the iFramed page.  Look at the source code for any URL that does not begin with https://.

You will have to look very closely at all your resource references.

Comment: (Protocol relative URLs - e.g. "//.." - are also acceptable.)

Comment: What's weird is that these errors do not appear when I'm using IE8 and above.... any guesses? I used the <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> btw

Comment: Would you be able to share the source of your page or the location the iFrame points to?

Comment: @FrankO I wish I could but I don't think I can. Do you think putting a meta tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>  on the iFrame-d page would solve the problem? Since the error does not appear or ie8 and above

Comment: Have you reviewed all the resources references in your page(s)?  Does the iFrame have CSS or javascript that make other resource calls?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that it's the `<iframe>` that is causing your problem. Do as @JonathonReinhart suggested and comment it out so that you can ascertain that your issue is from there. (Edit: never mind, it appears that the `<iframe>` is indeed your issue)

2) Browsers are very sensitive to iframes because they can access content that is a) not yours and b) insecure. In general, though, whenever you have an HTTPS page that accesses anything (scripts, frames, images) from an HTTP page, it'll throw you a warning. However, with iframes, the browser will shut you down, with most of them disabling the iframe completely unless the user confirms that they want to access the content. I'm not sure how lenient IE6 is with this, but if there's anything that's the slightest bit fishy about the way you're accessing the content, the browser is not going to like it. You shouldn't have an issue if the HTTPS page is accessing HTTPS content, but you need to scope out all of your resources (perhaps in another browser?) to make sure that you're accessing everything securely.

3) Also keep in mind that the page you're accessing (though it may be secure itself) may access insecure resources. I would recommend going to that page and checking its resources as well, because the browser will still count it accessing those resources insecurely as your page accessing them insecurely.